# How to have a a razor action link open in a new tab?

Tags: c#, html, razor

I trying to get my link to open in a new tab (it must be in razor format):

```
    <a href="@Url.Action("RunReport", "Performance", new { reportView = Model.ReportView.ToString() }, new { target = "_blank" })" type="submit" id="runReport" class="button Secondary">@Reports.RunReport</a>
```

This is not working though.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why would you bother attempting to put that into `Url.Action`? Just put in the `<a>` tag itself.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Looks like you are confusing [Html.ActionLink()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx) for [Url.Action()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx).  Url.Action has no parameters to set the Target, because it only returns a URL.

Based on your current code, the anchor should probably look like:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("RunReport", "Performance", new { reportView = Model.ReportView.ToString() })" 
   type="submit" 
   id="runReport" 
   target="_blank"
   class="button Secondary">
     @Reports.RunReport
</a>
```

Answer (score 138):

Just use the `HtmlHelper` `ActionLink` and set the `RouteValues` and `HtmlAttributes` accordingly.

```
@Html.ActionLink(Reports.RunReport, "RunReport", new { controller = "Performance", reportView = Model.ReportView.ToString() }, new { target = "_blank" })
```

Answer (score 23):

That won't compile since `UrlHelper.Action(string,string,object,object)` doesn't exist.

`UrlHelper.Action` will only generate Urls based on the action you provide, not `<a>` markup. If you want to add an HtmlAttribute (like `target="_blank"`, to open link in new tab) you can either:

- Add the target attribute to the `<a>` element by yourself:

  ```
  <a href="@Url.Action("RunReport", "Performance",
      new { reportView = Model.ReportView.ToString() })",
      target = "_blank" type="submit" id="runReport" class="button Secondary">
      @Reports.RunReport
  </a>
  ```
- Use Html.ActionLink to generate an `<a>` markup element:

  ```
  @Html.ActionLink("Report View", "RunReport", null, new { target = "_blank" })
  ```

Answer (score 18):

If your goal is to use the ActionLink helper and open a new tab:

```
@Html.ActionLink("New tab please", "Home", null , new { target = "_blank" })

@Html.ActionLink("New tab please", "Home", Nothing, New With {Key .target = "_blank"})
```

Answer (score 9):

```
@Html.ActionLink(
"Pay Now",
"Add",
"Payment",
new { @id = 1 },htmlAttributes:new { @class="btn btn-success",@target= "_blank" } )
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 7):

With Named arguments:

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "TestTab", actionName: "TestAction", controllerName: "TestController", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { target = "_blank"})
```

Answer (score 7):

For

> @Url.Action

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" target="_blank">Link Text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

asp.net mvc ActionLink new tab with angular parameter

```
<a  target="_blank" class="btn" data-ng-href="@Url.Action("RunReport", "Performance")?hotelCode={{hotel.code}}">Select Room</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting it't `type` as `submit`. That means that browser should post your `<form>` data to the server.

In fact a tag has no type attribute according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).

So remote `type` attribute and it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="@Url.Action("RunReport", "Performance", new { reportView =     Model.ReportView.ToString() })"  type="submit"    id="runReport"  target="_blank"  class="button Secondary"> @Reports.RunReport </a>`